# add loader to ajax code

Tags: php, ajax

I have ajax script that print comment
I would like to add loader while the server query works

what do I need to add to the "success" in order to see LOADER in my html page?

```
function printComments (obj) {

    var element = $(obj);
    var contactID = element.attr("contactID");
    var type = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'contactID=' + contactID + "&type=" + type + "&catID=" + catID;
    $("#loader").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">');
//  alert(info);


     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/followPrint.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(msg){


            if (type == "followsTab")
                $("#follows").html(msg);
            if (type == "commentsTab")
                $("#commentsContent").html(msg);    
       }
     });

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just play with hide() and show() like,

```
function printComments (obj) {

    var element = $(obj);
    var contactID = element.attr("contactID");
    var type = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'contactID=' + contactID + "&type=" + type + "&catID=" + catID;
    $("#loader").show(); // displaying loader here


     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/followPrint.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(msg){
            if (type == "followsTab")
                $("#follows").html(msg);
            if (type == "commentsTab")
                $("#commentsContent").html(msg);    

             $("#loader").hide(); // hiding loader here

           }
     });

    //return false; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
HTML

<a href="#" id="verification" >test</a>
<img src="example_preloader.gif" id="ajaxPreloader" style="display:none" />
```

JS

```
$('#verification').click(function() {
    $('#ajaxPreloader').toggle();
    $.ajax({
       type     : "POST",
       url      : "example url",
       data     : {'exampleData': ''},
       success : function(msg) {
        $('#ajaxPreloader').text('');
        location.reload();
       },
       error:    function(error) {
        $('#ajaxPreloader').text('');
       }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use beforeSend to show the loader and then in succes function hide that loader

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/followPrint.php",
    data: info,
    beforeSend:function(){
      $("#loader").show();
     },
    success: function(msg){

        $("#loader").hide();
        if (type == "followsTab")
            $("#follows").html(msg);
        if (type == "commentsTab")
            $("#commentsContent").html(msg);    
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/followPrint.php",
        data: info,
        **beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader").html("<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">");
            },**
        success: function(msg){    
             $('#loader').hide();
            if (type == "followsTab")
                $("#follows").html(msg);
            if (type == "commentsTab")
                $("#commentsContent").html(msg);    
       }
     });
```

**added this line of code extra:**

```
beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loader").html("<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">");
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

function printComments (obj) {

```
var element = $(obj);
var contactID = element.attr("contactID");
var type = element.attr("id");
var info = 'contactID=' + contactID + "&type=" + type + "&catID=" + catID;
$("#follows").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$("#commentsContent").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">');
```

//loader will hide replaced by output while the server query works

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/followPrint.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(msg){


        if (type == "followsTab")
            $("#follows").html(msg);
        if (type == "commentsTab")
            $("#commentsContent").html(msg);    
   }
 });

return false;
```

}